# How could i change my state from getCellActions

Tags: reactjs, callback, state, react-data-grid

I am new in react. For my project i want to change my state by clicking an icon from table which will change my state. I am using getCellActions (react-data-grid). How could I pass my custom function alone with column and row object.

Thanks in advance.

NT: I am not using redux

```
getCellActions(column, row, state) {

        if(column.key === 'modify'){
            return [
                {
                    icon: 'fa fa-edit',
                    callback: () => {
                        console.log(row.id);
                       //this.getRoleData();
                    }
                }
            ];

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use ES6 and pass an arrow function expression that simply invokes the function you want and binds the function with `this` automatically..

In react-data-grid, you would have to do something like below:

```
<ReactDataGrid
    columns={this._columns}
    rowGetter={this.rowGetter}
    rowsCount={this._rows.length}
    minHeight={300}
    getCellActions= {(column, row) => this.getCellActions(column, row)}
    state = {this.state}
/>
```

And your `getCellActions` function can be as it is:

```
getCellActions(column, row) {

    if(column.key === 'modify'){
        return [
            {
                icon: 'fa fa-edit',
                callback: () => this.getRoleData(row.id)
            }
        ];

    }
}
```

The thing is that when you write:

```
getCellActions= {(column,row) => this.getCellActions(column, row)}
```

you actually pass an anonymous function which will only be executed when triggered. 
I would like to add that when you write an arrow function in one line, it automatically returns that statement, except you wrap that line in curly braces and write a normal function. So, the above line works as :

```
getCellActions= {(column,row) => return this.getCellActions(column, row)}
```

So, the MANTRA is: return the reference, do not execute it before the trigger.

Comment: That makes the sense. With bind that callback function called twice and it worked. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

The problem why `this.getRoleData()` is not working, is because `this` inside of your callback is not in the context of your component.

Change your `getCellActions` function to an [arrow function](https://codeburst.io/javascript-arrow-functions-for-beginners-926947fc0cdc), so you have the component as context (inside a arrow function this keeps its meaning from its original context):

```js
import React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedRowId: null
        };
    }

    myCallback = (rowId) => {
        console.log(rowId);
        this.setState({ selectedRowId: rowId });
    };

    getCellActions = (column, row, state) => {

        if(column.key === 'modify'){
            return [
                {
                    icon: 'fa fa-edit',
                    callback: () => {
                        console.log(row.id);
                        this.myCallback(row.id);
                    }
                }
            ];

        }
    }

    render() {
        // your render function...
    }
}
```

**Alternative:**

Bind `this` to `getCellActions` in the constructor like:

```
this.getCellActions = this.getCellActions.bind(this);
```

Comment: callback is already an arrow function. But binding 'this' solved it thanks a lot mate.

Comment: @anikislamShojib Yes, you are right, `callback` is an arrow function, but `getCellActions` is not - so the context of the `callback` is the `getCellActions` function and not your component with your state.
Thats why binding `this` to `getCellActions` solved you problem (which is the same as changing it to an arrow function)